# Creating 3D graphs on python with connecting lines

Tags: python, 3d, graphing

i need to make a graph that looks something like that!

[the 3d plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cery.png)

i have 4 dimentions points (time,x,y,z), and i want to make the graph with connecting lines+ the two little graphs with The probability distributions by the given data..

thanks

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. [Please read through this guide on posting questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is not complete I would like to give you a hint :)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Cheers, do post well constructed questions.